# WinSCP and ASCII_RECSEP

Tags: ftp, ftp-client, winscp

What's the equivalent in WinSCP for this command:

`quote "SITE ASCII_RECSEP=NONE"`

Is it just `-transfer=binary` when using `put` command or it's something completely different?

From what I read it says like it's related to FTP streaming behavior. And it looks like this quote is used just to execute this `SITE` command on remote FTP server. But I'm not sure how to change my builtin FTP script (that part that I mentioned above) to work with WinSCP.

It looks like I need to use this `call` command?

https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use the [`call` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_call):

```
call SITE ASCII_RECSEP=NONE
```

With the FTP protocol, the WinSCP `call` command is an equivalent of the `literal` command (and its `quote` alias) of the Windows `ftp.exe`.

See a section on the [`literal` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ftp_script_to_sftp#literal) in the [guide for converting Windows FTP script to WinSCP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ftp_script_to_sftp).

And follow the quide for other issues you may encounter, when converting your script.